# nginx php Class "HttpRequest" not found

Tags: php, nginx, httprequest

I use **nginx** and get the following error message.

**Fatal error: Class 'HttpRequest' not found**

I installed **pecl_http** extension and added *extension=http.so* in php.ini file.

Still i get same error. Please give me a solution.

Also tell me how to check if pecl_http is installed properly or not ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using php-fpm, you'll need to restart it after changing the ini file. The phpinfo() function will give you a bunch of output, including what ini file was used, and what extensions where loaded.